# Leopard gecko's toe looks blackish purple

Tags: leopard-geckos, geckos, molting

My son's leopard gecko's toe doesn't look good. We thought it may have turned purple because of shedding. We've tried soaking it. Nothing seems to be working. Its toenail looks a bit black too. Does anyone know what is going on here?

[image]

Comment: Looks like a toe, in that photo... not much different from the next toe over. If the animal is gripping with it...

Answer (score 3):

It's just from clogged up skin but your gecko could lose its toes due to blood circulation being cut off.

Just soak it in warm water for ten minutes then get a cotton ball and rub and pat gently till its clogged skin comes off. This process should remain gentle: do not force skin off with fingers.

To avoid this happening again keep your gecko in a cage with a moist environment and replace sand with a mat. Make sure his favorite hiding spot stays moist too.